# How to delete Grammarly extension from Safari?

Tags: safari, applications, safari-extensions, macos

When I try to delete Grammarly extension from Safari, it says:

> The “Grammarly for Safari” extension is part of the “Grammarly for Safari” application.
>
> To uninstall “Grammarly for Safari”, you must remove the “Grammarly for Safari” application.

And when I try to delete it from the Finder, it says:

> The item “Grammarly for Safari” can’t be moved to the Trash because some of its extensions are in use.

How do I break this deadlock?

MacOS: High Seirra 10.13.6; Safari: 12.0.3; Grammarly: 9.4

Comment: You can try disabling(all of them, from Develop Menu ), not deleting the extension and then removing the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trying, I figured it out.

Close all the apps that might be using Grammarly and delete it from finder.

No need to remove the extension from Safari after that.